# I want to know how much data was received and sent via Wi-Fi on a Mac

Tags: macos, networking, command-line

There are some plans in my mobile carrier. For example 7GB/month, 10GB/month, 20GB/month etc. To decide good plan I want to know how many data was received and sent via Wi-Fi. Is there any commands or apps to do like this. Any hints are welcome.

Note: I use my mobile phone mainly as Wi-Fi router. So I want to know how much data was received or sent from my Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) machine to the router.

Comment: An iPhone under data usage will have personal hotspot usage. Not I/O specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity Monitor is a free piece of software for tracking bandwidth of a single computer.  Its included by default with your Mac. Just open spotlight and type "activity monitor".  It will pop up a window. Go to the network tab and it will show you how much data you used since your last reboot.  Then you can leave your computer on for a while and get an average.

Comment: It almost solve my problem. And I used `uptime` command to measure the time from the last reboot. It turned out I transfer and recieve 1.25GB/day. Thanks.